# Using the DOM to Call Multiple Functions and Append Elements

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm currently practicing with using the DOM and manipulating it. Right now, I'm practicing with creating code for a general clicker style game. The tools goes up every time that tool is clicked and I have a builder that a player can purchase and open/unlock (if the count of the tools is enough to purchase).

I am having a hard time trying to call multiple functions, but also while manipulating the DOM by appending div elements (if that makes sense). I know that I will have to loop thru the data below and then outside of the loop I would need to append some div elements to the builder container.

The data that I'm working with:

```
data = {
        tools: 200,
        builders: [
          { id: 'builder_A', price: 100, unlocked: false },
          { id: 'builder_B', price: 400, unlocked: false },
          { id: 'builder_C', price: 700, unlocked: false }
        ]
      };
```

The specs that I'm working with:

```
           calls document.getElementById()
        
        appends some builder div elements to the builder container
        const builderContainer = document.getElementById('builder_container');
        assert.isAbove(builderContainer.childNodes.length, 0);
    
        unlocks any locked builders that need to be unlocked
          code.renderBuilders(data);
          expect(data.builders[0].unlocked).to.be.equal(true);
          expect(data.builders[1].unlocked).to.be.equal(true);
          expect(data.builders[2].unlocked).to.be.equal(false);
        
        only appends unlocked builders
      code.renderBuilders(data);
      const builderContainer = document.getElementById('builder_container');
      expect(builderContainer.childNodes.length).to.be.equal(2);
      expect(builderContainer.childNodes[0].childNodes).to.have.length(5);
        
        deletes the builder container's children before appending new builders
const builderContainer = document.getElementById('builder_container');
      const fakeBuilder = document.createElement('div');
      container.appendChild(fakeBuilder);
      code.renderBuilders(data);
      expect(builderContainer.childNodes.length).to.be.equal(2);
      expect(builderContainer.childNodes[0].childNodes).to.have.length(5);
```

Here is the code that I've written thus far:

```
    function renderBuilders(data) {
  let builderContainer = document.getElementById('builder_container');
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const newBuilder = currentBuilder; // storing the current builder in a new variable, but not sure if this would be the correct route?
    currentBuilder = makeBuilderDiv(); // which already creates a builder container div
     
    let deletedBuilder = deleteAllChildNodes(); // this function deletes the builder container's children before appending new builders

    let unlockedBuilder = getUnlockedBuilders(); // this function would unlock any locked builders that need to be unlocked
  }
  builderContainer.appendChild(builder);

}
```

However, but when I'm trying to append outside of the loop, I'm getting this error (for a different function that was already created):

```
function updateToolsPerSecondView(tps) {
  const tpsView = document.getElementById('tps');
  tpsView.innerText = tps;
}
TypeError: Attempted to wrap getElementById which is already wrapped
```

I believe I'm going to have to call those 3 functions in the loop and possibly create new variables to store, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing in the loop itself and why I'm getting the error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Whether your code execute in the loop or not, `getElementById` should be executed once. The error message says `TypeError: Attempted to wrap getElementById which is already wrapped`, which one of tags with the function has a tag as itself. In the function `updateToolsPerSecondView` it changed tpsView inner text to a html tag. It should be a string. You may change like from

`tpsView.innerText = tps;`

to

`tpsView.innerText = tps.innerText;`

`tpsView.innerText` can not have tag as its value.